# Extract text from multiline string such as a key value string

Tags: excel

I have  a cell text in Excel with like the following

Cell A1:

```
Key1: Value1
Key2: Value2
 Key3: Value3
 Key Name4: Value4
Key5: Value5
```

Now I would like to extract `Value4` given that i know its key is `Key Name4`, any suggestion using Excel formulas?

PS: there is a space before my interested key

Comment: So this is all in one cell?

Comment: yes..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another using SEARCH which is case insensitive:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(B2,A1)+LEN(B2)+1,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),A1,SEARCH(B2,A1))-SEARCH(B2,A1)-LEN(B2),LEN(A1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I just fixed my formula as I had the same glitch you still have: it fails to retrieve `Key5`. I fixed it with an `IfError` on the last part when `Char(10)` cannot be found thereafter anymore.

Comment: Now your formula is almost the same as mine. You just used `search` instead of `find`: case-sensitive vs case-insensitive

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the key value you are searching for is in `B4` the following should work:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(B4,A1)+LEN(B4)+2,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),MID(A1,FIND(B4,A1)+LEN(B4)+2,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oooooh fancy you with the .gif. :)

Comment: Wait maybe its because of office in another langauge doh

Comment: @giò I used `FIND` which is case-sensitive. So, you need to search for `Key Name4` and **not** `key nAmE4`. For the solution provided by @ScottCraner that's not the case. He used `SEARCH` instead of `FIND` which is case-insensitive. So, you can search for `key name4` or `key NaMe4` or `KEY NAME4`...

Comment: @Ralph he means that the function names are not in English in his version of Excel http://superuser.com/questions/1055511/function-names-in-international-versions-of-excel

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("Key Name4: ",A1)+10,9999),FIND("Key5",MID(A1,FIND("Key Name4: ",A1)+10,9999))-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how my VBA solution would work:

[image]

That is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function TakeMeAValue(rngRange As Range, lngCounter As Long)

    Application.Volatile
    Dim lngStart        As Long
    Dim lngEnd          As Long
    Dim strWord         As String: strWord = "Key"
    Dim strWordToSearch As String

    On Error GoTo TakeMeAValue_Error

    strWordToSearch = CStr(strWord & lngCounter & ":")
    lngStart = InStr(1, rngRange, strWordToSearch) + Len(strWordToSearch)
    lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, rngRange, strWord & lngCounter + 1)

    If lngEnd = 0 Then
        lngEnd = Len(rngRange) + 1
    End If

    TakeMeAValue = Trim(Mid(rngRange, lngStart, (lngEnd - lngStart)))

    Exit Function

TakeMeAValue_Error:
    TakeMeAValue = err.Description

End Function
```